# Are there any tools out there that can 'trick' keyloggers?

Tags: keyloggers, cipher-selection

Are there any tools out there that can 'trick' keyloggers? I was wondering if there's any 'enigma-style' tools available along the lines of providing time-randomised keyboard mappings. For example:

- If I want to enter my password, and the first letter is 'Q' then I would press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>
- However, if <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is currently mapped to `#` this is what the keylogger would detect
- The software would then be able to translate this `#` to `Q` when typing into my password field

Comment: I'm not sure how useful such a tool would be. If there's malware running on your machine, you've already lost. If you're trying to set up a honeypot to catch keyloggers, just use a fake account. Simple keyloggers can be defeated by password managers and certain types of on-screen keyboards, without any need for complicated mappings between keys. (Again though; malware. The attacker effectively owns your machine at that point.)

Comment: Avast Antivirus (SafeZone) has a method in which they form a direct* pipe to the keyboard itself. This effectively blocks keyboard access from all but the lowest of the low OS processes. I'm not even sure if the OS processes has access. Look into that.

Comment: @PandaLion98 - considering Avast installs junk without the user's approval, using it to combat keyloggers looks suspiciously close to fighting fire with napalm.

Comment: @DeerHunter Google Chrome and Dropbox are the only non-Avast junk I found so far. Nothing malicious. <> And yes, napalm can possibly put out a fire by carefully burning surrounding areas using it. http://science.howstuffworks.com/nature/natural-disasters/fight-fire-with-fire1.htm